# queries on JBPM

Tags: hibernate, android-activity, process, jbpm, migrate

1)    For Example we need execute delete statement, where do we set it? In JBPM or in Hibernate?

2)   Does JBPM requires specific Database?

3)    How to archive data in JBPM?

4)    How to maintain database in JBPM?

5)     How to restart a failed activity/task in JBPM?
          Public and Process type example

6)     Is it possible to migrate from 3.0 to 5.0?

```
 6.1 )   Are they compatible?    
 6.2 )   How to migrate from 3.0 to 5.0
 6.3 )   What are the things/changes to be considered upon migration.
 6.4 )   What are the possible impacts of migrating from 3.0 to 5.0
 6.5 )    What would be the impact in the existing library of the 3.0?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Q) how to archive data in JBPM?

A) Archive A collection of historical records,or a physical place where they are located
    https://community.jboss.org/message/622804#622804
   According to above link  a store procedure is the best option for archiving old data that is not needed anymore.
   or 
    - don't care about old history, just remove/delete.
    - have BAM reporting in place so have to keep, then migrate out to a different format/location/db to allow for        continued reporting.
    - apply enterprise process (for example, I worked in an enterprise that applied data warehousing techniques) to       collect and store for reporting all history data
    - leave it in place, but be prepared to eventually have to enlarge your DB machine! ;-)

```
http://docs.jboss.com/jbpm/v3/userguide/jpdl.html
```

JPDL specifies an xml schema and the mechanism to package all the process definition related files into a process       archive.
    Deploying process archives can be done in 3 ways: with the process designer tool, with an ant task or            programatically.

Q ) How to restart a failed activity/task in JBPM?

A ) Tasks are never started automatically but always manual. If a task was in progress when the server was shut down , the      transaction should be rolled back and the task should be available in the tasklist again.
    If jBPM runs in the same transaction as the calling method (the one that signals in the first case) that will be rolled     back as well. So 'transaction management' is fully supported.

Q ) Is it possible to migrate from 3.0 to 5.0?
    Are they compatible?
    How to migrate from 3.0 to 5.0
    What are the things/changes to be considered upon migration.
    What are the possible impacts of migrating from 3.0 to 5.0

A )  Well yes it is possible to migrate from 3.0 to 5.0, acxtually migration project is under development phase.
    So whether it is compatible or not ,we can't commment on that as of now.
    Steps of how to migrate will also be known afterwards,and what things are things/changes to be considered will also         be known later on and also its impacts.

Well for refrence please follow this link as this quick guide can help you, and you will get answers to your        doubts/ questions here.

```
http://www.schabell.org/2011/10/jbpm-migration-tooling-available-in.html

www.schabell.org .
```

Q ) For Example we need execute delete statement, where do we set it? In JBPM or in Hibernate?
    Does JBPM requires specific DB?
    How to maintain database in JBPM?

A ) Now integration of JBPM with Spring is still left , so if we are able to to do that than we can easily execute any database queries in project, and JBPM is very flexible we can use any database in our project by making      changes in persistence.xml file i.e.,by adding the dialect and driver of database which we require,by default jbpm      uses H2 database.

Q ) Now can we use two databases in our project?

A ) -

Q ) How to maintain Database in JBPM ?

A ) -

Comment: Well aal these answers are according to my understanding well i am not sure of them .these are my views and thinking and knowledge. I may be wrong also